# How to reload div with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have the JavaScript function:

```
function notificationDivPressed(element,userId,numberOfUsers) {
$.ajax({
        url: '/Notification/ChangeReadStatus',
        type: "POST", cache: false,
        data: { arg: userId },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#NotificationsContainer').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

there is 'NotificationsContainer' div:

```
<div id="NotificationsContainer" class="NotivicationsContainerHeader">
  <span>თქვენ გაქვთ <span>@ViewBag.NewMessages</span> ახალი შეტყობინება</span>
</div>
```

this JavaScript function makes change in database and also changes 'ViewBag.NewMessages' value. So I want to refresh this  only, not whole page and show new value of 'ViewBag.NewMessages'

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, create the response of the `ViewBag.NewMessage` at the server-side using the ASP.NET Language and  do the database queries what you want to do and then create the result, then the `data` will have its; ViewBag.NewMessage's value. Try to change the div as

```
<span class="viewbag">@ViewBag.NewMessages</span>
```

And now, just update it as:

```
success: function (data) {
  $('.viewbag').html(data);
}
```

This way, only the span with the ViewBag will get updated and not the whole of the page.

So when the ajax would provide some value, it will replace the current values with the new ones and you will have the new value for that ViewBag written on the page on success.

Comment: You're most welcome! :) You surely can try out .. @GodoJobadze :)

Comment: That is because there is no response to be written here. Try to write this on the other page: `Response.Write("This is resonse");` this will write the response..similarly write the new value of the ViewBag as a response..

Answer (score 1):

The ViewBag object inherits the asp.net session object, it can't be accessed from outside of .net.